# HTML5 → Dynamic associated Server Sent Events

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, push, server-sent-events

I just started using SSE and wonder how I can make them more dynamic.

I'm using a  Box to select users and an image and text changes corresponding to the username.
Now I want to check for user updates via SSE and want the user to be still selectable.

I tried to add the *eventSource* when I'm changing the `<select>` box:

```
function setSelected(elm) {
    selectedName = elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

    var eSource = new EventSource("getState.php?passVar=" + selectedName);
    eSource.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("stateText").innerHTML = event.data;
    };
}
```

How can I reach my goal?

**edit**
I have now added the eventSource successfully (I had an issue with the source itself).

But when I now add another source, I have actually two sources running.
How can I remove the old one?

Comment: Why is your current approach not working?

Comment: I now could add a source. But I can't remove the old one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the previous event source use the [`close()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Server-sent_events/EventSource#close%28%29).  You're going to have to keep the reference to `eSource` around somehow to do this.

Comment: I already tried to call `close()` but I couldn't keep the reference because the method would be called the first time too (when eSource is not defined). I now got it working with the following code: `if (typeof(eSource) != "undefined") {
                    eSource.close();
                }`